# Is there a way I can add unicode text to a MBCS MFC menu

Tags: unicode, mfc, localization

I have a MFC application compiled with the MBCS character set.  I have a submenu off of my main menu that I would like to add unicode characters to.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the use of Unicode strings even in MBCS apps by explicitely calling the Unicode form of an API and passing it a Unicode string.

In your case, ModifyMenuW() is the API that sets the menu item text (assuming the menu item already exists):

```
ModifyMenuW(GetMenu()->m_hMenu,ID_APP_ABOUT, MF_BYCOMMAND , 0, L"\u573F");
```

This code displays a Chinese ideogram (I have no idea of its meaning) instead of the original text

The `L` in front of the string says it's a Unicode string. `\u573F` is the way you encode a Unicode char in your C++ ASCII source file. The `W` at the end of the API name: It stands for *Wide* and denotes the Unicode form of the API.

Note that if your goal is to translate the full UI of your app, this is a complete other story: The method I showed here is only suitable for one-shot calls. You can't create a full UI that way.

You can translate your MBCS app to Japanese, Russian, whatever,... without switching to Unicode (Although it would be a very good idea to do that switch. But that can be costly for legacy apps).

You have 2 friends to help you out there: [appTranslator](http://www.apptranslator.com) lets you very easily translate your app (and manage your translations (Disclaimer: This is my own ad ;-) and [Microsoft AppLocale](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13209) helps you test MBCS apps in different codepages without actually changing the codepage of your computer (which requires a reboot).

Comment: InsertMenuW(m_hMenu,i,MF_BYPOSITION,j,L"\u573F") just gives me a ? in my menu.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Which OS? If XP: Do you have support (iow fonts) for East Asian Languages installed?

Comment: WIndows 7 Ultimate.  I have the chinese code page installed though it is not active.

Comment: Weird :-( 1st: With Vista+, East Asian fonts are installed by default. I added this line at the end of my CMainFrame::OnCreated() and it works fine: InsertMenuW(GetMenu()->m_hMenu,0,MF_BYPOSITION,10000,L"\u573F") ;

Comment: This will work UNLESS you are using the MFCFeaturePack and are using a CMFCMenuBar.  The CMFCMenuBar stores the menu text internally in a CString which breaks this approach