# Why am I getting a question mark in my menu in place of a unicode character?

Tags: winapi, unicode, localization, mfc-feature-pack

I have a MFC application compiled with MBCS.  We are also using the CMFCMenuBar from the MFC Feature Pack to display our menu.

I am trying to add unicode characters to my menu using the following code (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944178/is-there-a-way-i-can-add-unicode-text-to-a-mbcs-mfc-menu))

```
MENUITEMINFOW mi;
mi.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFOW);
mi.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_TYPE;
mi.fType = MFT_STRING;
mi.wID = 34503; 
WCHAR text[128];
wcscpy_s(text,L"\u573F");
mi.dwTypeData = text;
InsertMenuItemW(hMenu,1,true,&mi);
```

The runs fine and the return code of InsertMenuItemW is 1, but I get a question mark in my menu instead of 圿

Why am I getting the question mark?

I am running Windows7 Ultimate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is creating MBCS windows, not Unicode windows.  Because it uses CreateWindowExA() instead of CreateWindowExW().  Verify this with Spy++.  Use its finder tool to pick a window in your program, look at its properties.  A window has "(Unicode)" marked for the Window Proc if it was created with CreateWindowExW().

Time to move to Unicode.

Comment: Of course I missed the obvious hint that it was a MBCS application. Good answer.